# Searching for contents in huge number of files in java

Tags: java, io, readfile

We are building search feature in our application to traverse over more than 100,000 xml files for content.
Data content are in form of huge number of xml files.

**Is this a good idea to keep huge number of xml files and on search (like by name etc) traverse through each file for result?** It may reduce our application search performance.

Or what is the best way?

Comment: Searching 100,000 un-indexed xml files for data will never, ever be a best way to do something(especially if you are planning on searching through them all for each search).  You should read this data into a database or some other index based search so that you can find information that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) here.  It will give you what you need.

Comment: Rick Will elasticsearch work for file content search? Can you please route me to example if any?

Comment: Absolutely.  That is what elasticsearch is built for.  Start with this tutorial: http://www.elasticsearchtutorial.com/elasticsearch-in-5-minutes.html.  Once you are done with that, you want to look at the attachment mapper plugin.  Just search on elasticsearch.org for this.  ES can take a file passed as a string, index it completely, and have its contents be immediately available for search.